# Custom sAPO queries

Tags: windows, audio, system, wdk

I am new to driver develeopement, Please help
I have downloaded SwapAPO sample and built successfully. 
My questions are

1. SwapApo is kernal driver or user mode driver?
2. Do we need to associate this driver to specific device? or can I use it for all device?
3. I want to use this dll for all devices? Do I get steps to install SwapAPO dll?
4. Do we need to create ceritificate to test?
5. DO we need to follow windows certification test to upload to windows store?

Thanks in advance

Math

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I believe you would get more helpful attention if you broke this question to multiple separate questions (at least split the question about sAPO/SwapAPO/SwapApo and certification). How much have you done research yourself? It does not show in your question. It would also help to provide a web link describing sAPO/SwapAPO/SwapApo; this way people who in general are familiar with driver/audio programming could help even if they do not know about sAPO/SwapAPO/SwapApo - and the questions would be useful for wider audience who are struggling with similar issues.